# If I have an array of objects [{..},{..},..], how can I isolate a specific value in all objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects:

```
[{"id":2, "value": "Yellow", "property_id": 3, "created_at": "2019-21-10"},{"id":3, "value": "Blue", "property_id": 3, "created_at": "2019-21-10"},{"id":4, "value": "White", "property_id": 3, "created_at": "2019-21-10"},{"id":12, "value": "Green", "property_id": 3, "created_at": "2019-21-10"}]
```

Which is generated through this line of code:

```
allColours.find(colr => colr == this.templateColours.colour_id).colour_default_values
```

In each object I want to isolate all values under 'value' e.g. the end result should be:
[Yellow, Blue, White, Green].

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can solve this with a for loop or with `.map()`.

Comment: use `map`; I'm gonna call your array data, `data.map(ch => ch.value);` would return `[Yellow, Blue, White, Green]`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr = [{"id":2, "value": "Yellow", "property_id": 3, "created_at": "2019-21-10"},{"id":3, "value": "Blue", "property_id": 3, "created_at": "2019-21-10"},{"id":4, "value": "White", "property_id": 3, "created_at": "2019-21-10"},{"id":12, "value": "Green", "property_id": 3, "created_at": "2019-21-10"}];

const mappedArr = arr.map(item => item.value);
console.log(mappedArr);
```

Answer (score -1):

The hard way with [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
list.map(e => e.value)
```

With [Lodash `_.map`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#map) it's even easier:

```
_.map(list, 'value')
```

Answer (score -2):

The easiest way is to create a new array using `map()`:

```
const arr = [{"id":2, "value": "Yellow", "property_id": 3, "created_at": "2019-21-10"},{"id":3, "value": "Blue", "property_id": 3, "created_at": "2019-21-10"},{"id":4, "value": "White", "property_id": 3, "created_at": "2019-21-10"},{"id":12, "value": "Green", "property_id": 3, "created_at": "2019-21-10"}];
const colors = arr.map(o => o.value);
```